# Activate keyboard layout for Chinese and Japanese in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, keyboard, cjk

I am developing an application which according to an input locale identifier of a language *(ex: US keyboard -> "00000409" or German keyboard -> "00000407")* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values, activates a keyboard layout according to the language selected.

```
HKL desiredKeyboardLayout = LoadKeyboardLayout(idLanguage, 0);
ActivateKeyboardLayout(desiredKeyboardLayout, KLF_ACTIVATE);
```

Nevertheless, when I try to change the layout to Chinese or Japanese, the layout showed is *US Keyboard*...

Is there any way to activate layouts for these languages?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Did you check the return code?  If an error is indicated, GetLastError()?  Where you said "the layout showed is US Keyboard", was that via GetKeyboardLayoutName()?

Comment: Yes I did, the value returned of ActivateKeyboardLayout(..) function is the previous input locale identifier so it means that the function succeeds, nevertheless if I pass to the function input locale identifiers for japanese and chinese, the layout activated is the same that US Keyboard

Comment: Also, when I call GetKeyboardLayoutName(...) the buffer returned is the same that all input locale identifiers passed to LoadKeyboardLayout function

Comment: How do you know "the layout activated is the same that US Keyboard"?  If GetKeyboardLayoutName is confirming LoadKeyboardLayout, then that is the active keyboard layout.

Comment: Because when I load and activate the keyboard layout to German for example (idlanguage==L"00000407") , if I type the 'z' key the value written in display (ex. in notepad.exe) is 'y' (Germanic layout). If I load and activate the keyboard layout to Japanese (idLanguaje="00000411"), characters written are the same that in US keyboard "it doesn't write japanese characters"

Comment: Is that happening within your program?  The ActivateKeyboardLayout routine is only supposed to affect your process, not other processes.

Comment: No, this also changes the configuration of the keyboard layout of the operating system, for example input keys of the physical keyboard

Comment: Then MSDN documentation for [ActivateKeyboardLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646289(v=vs.85).aspx) is incorrect.

Comment: It's strange because the keyboard layout stays set on the language selected, even after I kill my application process

Comment: Seems like either a bug in the documentation, or a bug in the implementation.  Possibly both.  Either way, I think you get credit for finding a Microsoft bug, and there are not very many of those (although they do get a lot of fanfare).